# Is there a function that returns the probability of measuring a particular state in Cirq?

Tags: cirq

It is possible to use `cirq.simulate` and then the `final_state` keyword to get the final wavefunction of the circuit, however, the circuit that I am trying to simulate is very large, and the simulation seems to take a long time. Thus, I was wondering if there was a function that would allow me to find the probability of measuring the specific state that I'm interested in, rather than calculating the entire wavefunction (in turn hopefully helping to speed up the program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cirq's simulator is a state vector simulator, which cannot be told to focus on the amplitude of a specific output state or combination of output states.

Some tensor network based simulators can get benefit from focusing on a specific output state, but there isn't such a simulator in Cirq.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!